# How to combine xaml codes into one line

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, visual-studio, xaml

```
<Rectangle x:Name="HighlightBackground"
RadiusX="1"
RadiusY="1"
Opacity="0">
```

How to combine the above code into **one line** like following code?

```
<Rectangle x:Name="HighlightBackground" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" Opacity="0">
```

I mean is there an easy way for this when cleaning up xaml codes in the Visual Studio?

Comment: Do you mean, other than manually removing the line breaks?

Comment: @canton7   Yes it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are concerned about maintaining and keeping for XAML files clean, i would look at [Xaml Styler](https://github.com/Xavalon/XamlStyler/). This plugin helps to clean up XAML files and also give you the ability to customize how you want to arrange your XAML files